# What are the differences between sanitize and bypassSecurityTrustHtml in Angular?

Tags: angular

I want to know what are the differences  between the following:

```
import {Component, SecurityContext} from '@angular/core'

export class App {
  divContent: any;
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.divContent= sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, "divContent");
  }
```

and replacing sanitize with:

```
sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("divContent");
```

I expect to set the inner HTML of a div

```
<div [innerHTML]="divContent"></div>
```

In this case is the same to use either option ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer), the short answer to your question is that `sanitize` (the one you're currently using) is the safer and preferred approach in *most* cases.

`DomSanitizer.sanitize` will sanitize the value for you, such that it may be used in the given SecurityContext (HTML in your example):

```
sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, "divContent");
```

Quoting the docs,

> If a value is trusted for the context, this method will unwrap the contained safe value and use it directly. Otherwise, value [the 2nd parameter] will be sanitized to be safe in the given context, for example by replacing URLs that have an unsafe protocal part (such as `javascript:`). *The implementation is responsible to make sure that the value can definitely be safely used in the given context.*

`DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml` simply bypasses the security checks and assumes that the given value is safe HTML. The docs specify

> Only use [byPassSecurityTrustHtml] when the bound HTML is *unsafe* (e.g. contains `<script>` tags) and the code should be executed. The sanitizer will leave safe HTML intact, so in most situations this method should not be used.

Essentially, `sanitize` ensures that the value you pass to it will be safe by converting it if it is not already safe and leaving it alone if it is, while `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` blindly trusts that the HTML you provide is safe.